# .Net core Authorize attribute in inherited controller

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I am having some trouble with Authorization policies. I have a baseWebApiController with an action

```
[HttpDelete("{id}"), Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id) {}
```

But in a certain controller which inherits from the above I want to give access to users also, with a policy like:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}"), Authorize(Policy = "All")]
public override Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id){}
```

It seems regular users cannot access this action. Do I have to search further for errors in my policy configuration, or since the controller is inherited,m it's attributes are neglected?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute) is an attribute that is inherited and that allows itself to be applied multiple times.

That means when inheriting your method which already has an `AuthorizeAttribute`, that will be carried over. So the final function definition in your subclass would look like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]
[Authorize(Policy = "All")]
public override Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
```

So the route now has two policies in place. This is kind of a problem because policies are designed to be cumulative. So *all* policies have to pass in order for the authentication to succeed.

Of course, this will not work for you because you actually wanted to “wash out” the original policy from the base class. This is not possible though, so you would have to remove the policy from the base class and maybe introduce a second administrator-only class for those policies.

The general problem here is that your policy design seems to be based on *roles*. You are using policies, but effectively, you are checking on roles there. Instead, you should consider working with requirements: For example, to delete something, a user would need to fulfill the “DeletionAllowed” requirement. This allows for a much more fine-grained policy system. And the big benefit? Requirement handlers are disjunctive: So one handler that is able to fulfill the requirement is enough to pass it.